# UPDATED: Save a custom_field value when automatically creating a post using wp_insert_post

Tags: custom-post-types, users, user-meta, wp-insert-post, user-registration

The following code automatically creates a new post for a user when they are registered in a custom post type (`jt_cpt_team`) for team members.

The final missing part of the puzzle is to save the `$user_id` within a custom_field (`jt_user_id`) in the newly created post.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
class team_functions {

  public function __construct() {

    add_action('user_register', array($this, 'create_authors_page'), 999);

  }

  public function create_authors_page( $user_id ) {

    $the_user      = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $new_user_name = $the_user->user_login;
    $fname         = $the_user->first_name;
    $lname         = $the_user->last_name;
    $PostSlug      = $user_id;
    $PostGuid      = home_url() . "/" . $PostSlug;

    $my_post = array( 'post_title'   => $fname . '' . $lname,
                      'post_type'    => 'jt_cpt_team',
                      'post_content' => '',
                      'post_status'  => 'publish',
                      'post_theme'   => 'user-profile',
                      'guid'         => $PostGuid );

    $NewPostID = wp_insert_post( $my_post ); // Second parameter defaults to FALSE to return 0 instead of wp_error.

    $key   = 'jt_user_id'; // Custom Field Key
    $Value = $user_id;     // User ID is the custom_field value

    update_post_meta( $NewPostID, $Key, $Value );

    return $NewPostID;

  }


}
```

Props to [Felipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678703/automatically-create-a-post-for-each-user-using-wp-insert-post/38681631#38681631) for getting me this far btw :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** There was different capitalization on the variable `$key`

(`$Key` vs `$key`)

Always the simple things you miss eh? :)